# I need to change the font color for <![CDATA[ <p> ....</p> in my string.xml file

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-studio

I tried to change font color by using different methodology. But it doesn't work for anything. Please help me to change the font color.

```
<string name="story2">
<![CDATA[
<font color=#FFFFFF><center><i>FACT 2</i><br></center>
<center><b>MEETING WITH KIDS ALSO</b><br></center>
<p>As President, often Dr. Kalam’s office would receive requests from youngsters for a meeting with the country’s first citizen. Not only would Dr. Kalam meet the kids in his personal chambers at the Rashtrapati Bhavan, but he would also give them his precious time, “listen” to their ideas and provide feedback to the kids. On occasions, the President would follow up with such kids asking about the status of the ideas they discussed!</p>
</font>]]>
</string>
```

Comment: you can simply use textColor attribute inside your TextView. Why in strings.xml? any specific reason?

Comment: I am new to android. So I don't know how to show 10 stories within a single textview. So, I took dynamically whenever user press prev or next button.  Is there any other way of mentioning all the ten stories

Comment: That is a different question. Post another question with more details regarding what you want to achieve.